# How to change list.HeaderView(layout.textView) - dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a one `textView` in a layout that is dedicated to be header line of a list.

the layout - `list_header.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/list_header"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

and I call it from `main.java` (that display a list):

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
mList.addHeaderView(header);
```

I want to change the text attribute of the layout via code before display.
How do I do that ?

Comment: what kind of attribute you wan to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add an ID to your XML code like so:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textToChange
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    <!-- Remove this line because you won't need it -->
    android:text="@string/list_header"

    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Now in your main.java file, find the text view and set it's text like so:

```
//Declare this as a private variable:
private TextView textView1;

//Then, wherever your header declared, do this:
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textToChange);
textView1.setText("Your desired text");
```

Hope this helps!